# Is formula such as $\forall x\exists x( x\neq 0)$ allowed?

Tags: first-order-logic

[image]

In the book I am reading, it seems that $\forall x\exists x (x\neq 0)$ is also allowed. Why does it not restrict the times of occurrences of quantification of the same variable to be $\leq 1$ ? What does $\forall x\exists x( x\neq 0)$ mean here?

It's Raymond's First-order logic.

Comment: This is weird (and rarely used) but correct. $P:=(\exists x)(x\ne 0)$ has $x$ as a bound variable, i.e. the truth value of $P$ does not depend on anything - let's say $P$ is just true (e.g. in the set of real numbers). Then, $(\forall x)P$ (i.e. your original formula) also makes sense, even though it is trivial (for each $x$, $P$ is true, indeed). It is confusing because the "outer" $x$ and the "inner" $x$ are not the same $x$.

Comment: In the abstract, the book does not explicitly say that $\forall x:\exists x: \cdots$. In principle, once a variable is invoked, it is defined in the enclosed context and cannot be "redefined". Hence IMO $\exists x$ is illegal.

Comment: @Yves Daoust How do get to the assumption that a variable can not be redefined?

Comment: @Yuz Which book are you using?

Comment: @lemontree I am using Raymond's First-order logic. However I am not really intrested in it, i just need a definition of first-order logic, for something else.

Comment: @Yuz You mean Raymond Smullyan? See the edit in my answer on notation.

Comment: @lemontree Yes I saw it. Thank you alot. I am not familiar with this system but I totally got what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which textbook you're using. Some forbid vacuous quantification by defining

> If $x$ is a variable and $\phi$ is a formula **in which $x$ occurs free**, then $\forall x \phi$ and $\exists x \phi$ are formualas.

This would rule out prepending $\forall x$ to $\exists x (x \neq 0)$ because in $x$ occurs only bound, and also rule out applying $\forall x$ to $(1 \neq 0)$ because $x$ does not occur at all, whereas $\forall x (x \neq 0)$ would be allowed.

Usually though the restriction in bold is dropped, and that's what your textbook does too, so $\forall x \exists x (x \neq 0)$, and likewise a formula like $\forall x (1 \neq 0)$, is allowed. While vacuous quantification isn't very useful, it also doesn't hurt to have it, and additional restrictions just unnecessarily complicate the syntax of FOL.

It follows from the semantics of FOL that the first quantifier will be vacuous and only the inner one actually takes effect on the formula: With every quantifier the evaluation of the following formula happens under the modified assignment which maps the variable bound by the quantifier to whichever element is currently being iterated over, thereby "overriding" the variable assignment on the variable both of the initial variable assignment for free variables and quantifiers further out:

$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}\newcommand{\I}{\mathcal{I}}$
$\M \models \forall x \exists y (x \neq y)$
$\Longleftrightarrow \text{for all } v: \M, v \models \forall x \exists x (x \neq 0)$
$\Longleftrightarrow \text{for all } a \in \D: \M, v^{[x \mapsto a]} \models \exists y (x \neq 0)$
$\Longleftrightarrow \text{for all } a \in \D: \text{there exists } b \in \D: \M, v^{[x \mapsto a][x \mapsto b]} \models x \neq 0$
$\Longleftrightarrow \text{for all } a \in \D: \text{there exists } b \in D: v^{[x \mapsto a][x \mapsto b]}(x) \neq \I(0)$

By the definition of $v^{[x \mapsto d]}$:

$$v^{[x \mapsto d]}(u) = \begin{cases}d & \text{if } u = x\\v(u) & \text{else}\end{cases}$$

we get that $v^{[x \mapsto a][x \mapsto b]} = v^{[x \mapsto b]}$, so at any evaluation of the subformula $x \neq 0$, the value of $x$ will be that assigned by the existential quantifier, whereas the universal quantifier dose not actively take effect on anything, and the formula "means" in effect $\exists x (x \neq 0)$.

Edit: In the notation used in Smullyan, $v \models A_a^x$ instead of $v^{[x \mapsto a]} \models A$; but the mechanism is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Even assuming that the expression is "syntactically" valid, you can't assign a truth value to

$$\forall x:\exists x:x\ne0$$ because

$$\forall x':\exists x'':x'\ne0$$ is false and $$\forall x':\exists x'':x''\ne0$$ is true.

Comment: But $\forall x \exists x (x \neq 0)$ *is* $\forall x' \exists x'' (x'' \neq 0)$. The formula is not ambiguous and has a definite truth value.

Comment: @lemontree: your saying. Do you have any reference ?

Comment: See e.g. Dirk van Dalen, "Logic and Structure", p. 73 theorem 2.5.2 (iii): $\vDash \forall x \phi \leftrightarrow \phi$ if $x$ not free in $\phi$. That $\forall x \exists x (x \neq 0) \equiv \exists x (x \neq 0) \equiv \forall y \exists x (x \neq 0)$ directly follows from this.